# Split View Controller doesn’t release Detail View Controller after rotating to portrait

Tags: ios, swift, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a Split View Controller that is set up to have a master view controller with a table view that when a cell is tapped, presents a Detail View Controller through the use of `presentDetailViewController:`. Everything works fine until I select a cell, Detail View Controller is presented, rotate the device from collapsed to allVisible, rotate back to collapsed, tap the Back button in the navigation bar to return to the master view controller, and select the same or a different cell. What happens in this case is the first Detail View Controller that was shown does not get released, and a second Detail View Controller is shown (both are in memory according to the memory graph). However, without the rotation (selecting a cell and then tapping back, and then selecting the same/another cell) the first detail view controller is released (I put a print statement in the deinit method).

I’ve ruled out a strong reference to Detail View Controller because it does get released if there’s no rotation. Something about the split view controller showing the allVisible mode keeps the Detail View Controller in memory a. Even after navigating back b. Even after selecting another cell (which is when the view controller seems to be released when in entirely collapsed environment).

This is driving me nuts. Help?

Comment: I have the same issue - found a solution yet ?

Comment: @matt well split view controller can be collapsed or expanded in both portrait and landscape